# How to access prop passed to first tab in other tabs in react-native-router-flux?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-router-flux

I have a Router of react-native-router-flux and configured among others two tabs:

```js
<Scene key="page1" component={Page1} title="Page1" />
<Scene key="mytabs" tabs={true}>
    <Scene key="tab1" component={Tab1}/>
    <Scene key="tab2" component={Tab2}/>
</Scene>
```

I call my first tab and pass a prop like:

Actions.mytabs({id: 5});

This works fine and Tab1 component has access to that prop. But when clicking on the tab2 Navigation in  my Tabbar, I don't have this id available anymore. How I can store it. In the state of the Router? How do I do this?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Yes! I found the problem in 'Tab'.
Tabs are 'wrapped' by default - i.e. all children are wrapped by Stack with own nav bar. You may disable wrapping by using wrap={false} for Tabs and check passing props again.

```
<Scene key="Scene" tabs={true} wrap={false}> <Scene key="someTab" component={SomeTab} title="SomeTab" icon={TabIcon}/> <Scene key="Modal" component={Modal} title="Modal" hideNavBar direction="vertical"/> </Scene>
```

Here props are find when passing from someTab to Modal via Actions.Modal({someProp: theProp})

Answer (score 0):

I think its not possible to keep this information somehow magically. I build a simple workaround by storing the id in redux and read it from there in each tab's component. Works great.